# Block TFS Checkout for specific computer

Tags: tfs

In team foundation server (we are using 2012), is there a way to deny checkout or checkin of a certain file / folder based on the workspace or machine name?

Context: we have a DLL that uses the MS office PIAs.  My coworker keeps compiling it from his machine which causes the DLL to reference version 15 of the PIAs rather than 12 (office 2007).  This breaks in QA for machines that have office 2007 installed.

Update: We have the DLL's checked in to source control, so when my coworker compiles, he checks them in and all our environments end up getting them after they are deployed using TFS build.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the first part:

> there is no facility in TFS that blocks a computer by IP address

This is the reason that TFS build server is used for deployments to QA and Production. The build server builds directly from checked in source and in addition the office dll's can be versioned by checking them into tfs as well and referring to that directory as part of the build and the correct version will be used. Do not deploy from a developers workstation to QA for just the problem that you experienced.

Comment: We do use TFS build to deploy our environments.  Our project is a web site (not web application either) and we have a bin folder with the server DLLs checked in to source control.

Comment: So if you have the arrangement that I described why does it matter what a dev builds on a workstation since QA should be using the TFS builds

Comment: Well its kind of strange.  We dont recompile those DLL's for every deploy.  They get copied based on what is checked in.  The build machine compiles and publishes our DB projects and just it copies the websites (with the compiled DLLs) to their destination.